# C++ Is collection objects contain reference or value

Tags: c++

If I have a class:

```
class Model{
    Model();
};
Model model;
Model& ref=model;
```

and I want to store references for `Model` in a `Vector` collection, have I to declare models array as `std::vector<Model> models;` or `std::vector<Model&> models;`

Comment: You can't store references in a container unless you use [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper).

Comment: in this case should I use std::reference_wrapper or just simply use pointer?

Comment: _"in this case"_ Which case in particular? You didn't elaborate on your use case very much.

Comment: Excuse me, I mean is it better storing references or pointers in a vector?

Comment: I can't say finally without knowing your particular use case.

Comment: I am using OpenGL so I have Model class which loads and stores data for 3D models which may be large, I put them to a vector to iterate and render them each frame (may be 60 frame per second), I create each model once so should I use pointers "i know pointer is slower than reference specially with large classes and structs and may be unsafe" or using references?

Comment: _"i know pointer is slower than reference"_ Where did you get that myth from? I'd say they are fairly the same. I'd recommend you don't have any `Models` instantiated outside of the vector, but let it be the only place where they live. Use a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Model>>` for that, and access with raw pointers from the client code.

Comment: what is the feature of using std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Model>> over std::vector<Model*>?

Comment: Automatic dyynamic memory management.

Comment: I got it, thank you sir